# Docker Elasticsearch on VM

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I created a vm with Alpine-3.7 and I am trying to start a container with elasticsearch.
VM memory situation is:

```
alpine:~/elastic$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7483        242       7241          0         34        128
-/+ buffers/cache:         79       7404
Swap:         4095          0       4095
```

When I try to run elasticsearch I obtain this error:

```
elasticsearch    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000637299000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Operation not permitted' (errno=1)
elasticsearch    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007337ad000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Operation not permitted' (errno=1)
elasticsearch    | #
elasticsearch    | # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
elasticsearch    | # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
elasticsearch    | # Can not save log file, dump to screen..
elasticsearch    | #
elasticsearch    | # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
elasticsearch    | # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
elasticsearch    | # Possible reasons:
elasticsearch    | #   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
elasticsearch    | #   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
elasticsearch    | # Possible solutions:
elasticsearch    | #   Reduce memory load on the system
elasticsearch    | #   Increase physical memory or swap space
elasticsearch    | #   Check if swap backing store is full
elasticsearch    | #   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
elasticsearch    | #   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
elasticsearch    | #   Decrease number of Java threads
elasticsearch    | #   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
elasticsearch    | #   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
elasticsearch    | # This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
elasticsearch    | #
elasticsearch    | #  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2651), pid=29, tid=0x00007337c59ab700
```

I dont' copied all the error.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Did you follow the guidelines in this link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Comment: Looks like your problem connected with permission restrictions.

Comment: I solved setting:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262629/jvm-cant-map-reserved-memory-when-running-in-docker-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved setting this kernel parameter:

```
kernel.pax.softmode=1
```

with

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/pax/softmode
```

*Note: for reboots-persistent config add `kernel.pax.softmode=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`*

Thanks